# Large editable table: Want to prevent re-rendering of ALL rows upon modification of a table row

Tags: reactjs

**Explanation**

Because my table is being created / mapped by my `data` state hook and because my "handleAccountTypeOnChange" function modifies `data`, that function will **always** cause my TableRow component to re-render because it is modifying `data`.  so using `useCallback` wouldn't work in this scenario because of it's dependency on `data`.

How can I fix this?  I can restructure my table state in any way, flatten it more maybe.  But I still don't understand how I can solve this without passing in some sort of function that modifies the main data that wouldn't cause all the rows to render.  Is the only way to solve this is to use redux?  Would love to know how to accomplish this without it.

**EDIT**

made a codepen. Slightly different because no libraries but same concept.
https://codepen.io/daletron3030/pen/PoZqLOx

**Code**

i get data from my backend and i set it into my data.  for the sake of simplicity, my data looks like this:

App Component

```
const App = () => {
    const [data, setData] = React.useState([
      {
        username: "someUserName1",
        accountType: "admin",
      },
      {
        username: "someUserName2",
        accountType: "normal",
      }, // etc
    ]);

const handleAccountTypeOnChange = (e, {name, value}) => {
  const index = data.findIndex(account => account.username === name);
  setData(update(data, {[index]: {accountType: {$set: value}}}));
};

return (
  <>
    <Table>
      <Table.Body>
        {
          data.map((user, index) => (
            <TableRow
              key={index}
              handleAccountTypeOnChange={handleAccountTypeOnChange}
              username={user.username}
            />
          ))
        }
        </Table.Body>
    </Table>
  </>
)
```

TableRow Component

```
const TableRow = React.memo(({ handleAccountTypeOnChange, username }) => {

  const accountTypeOptions = [
    { key: "admin", value: "admin", text: "Administrator" },    
    { key: "normal", value: "normal", text: "Normal" }
  ];

  return (
    <>
      <Table.Row>
        <Table.Cell>
          <Dropdown
            name={username}
            onChange={handleAccountTypeOnChange}
            options={accountTypeOptions}
            selection
            value={accountType}
          />
        </Table.Cell>
        <Table.Cell>{username}</Table.Cell>
      </Table.Row>
    </>
  )});

export default TableRow;
```

Comment: Where is `const handleAccountTypeOnChange` defined? Is that in the same render function where you return `<Table.Body>`?

Comment: @RossAllen ah sorry I'll make an edit right now to make it more clear but no that's in the main component.  i can see how it's confusing.  it's similar to how i made the codepen though

Comment: @RossAllen made the edit.  let me know if it still isn't clear.  thanks for looking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a [functional update](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates) with your `setData` call, then the function never needs to change and it can be memoized with [`useCallback`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback):

```js
const handleAccountTypeOnChange = React.useCallback(
  (e, {name, value}) => {
    setData(prevData => {
      const index = prevData.findIndex(account => account.username === name);
      setData(update(prevData, {[index]: {accountType: {$set: value}}}));
    })
  },
  []
);
```

This `useCallback` does not need to list `setData` as a dependency because the callbacks returned from `useState` do not change over time.

Comment: AHHHH there's a prevData parameter that i friggin never knew about!!! thank you let me try

Comment: Yup! Check out the "functional updates" I linked in my answer.